# PL/SQL How to call a function without getting returned object

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, return-value, declaration

I have a function in PL/SQL:

```
FUNCTION do_something
  RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

This function can be called as such:

```
DECLARE
  answer BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  answer := do_something();
END
```

Now, there are cases, where I don't need the returned boolean. If I don't want to get it and just write:

```
do_something();
```

I get PLS-00306 (wrong number of types of arguments in call to DO_SOMETHING)
Is there a way to call it without declaring and setting a new boolean, which I will never use in this case?

Comment: Strange... I'd expect a `PLS-002221: 'do_something' is not a procedure or undefined` maybe because of the empty `()`. Anyway, not that I recomend it but you can put it in a `if` statement i.e. `IF(do_something) then null; end if;` but this is really ugly

Comment: Kind of strange as the point of a function is to return something, otherwise it should probably be a procedure.

Comment: @tbone, agreed; the function should be called something like `something_was_done()` :)

Comment: It's a valid question for java, c or pascal developers. Sometimes you really don't need return value and it makes code ugly. here's example:

`user_node := xmldom.appendChild(bund_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt));`

so after you append child to the parent object, you don't need a reference to that child.

Comment: Equally ridiculous as @A.B.Cade version. ```for x in (select do_something() from dual) loop exit; end loop;```. I'm starting to really hate plsql.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very simple: create a procedure which covers this function

```
PROCEDURE do_something
IS
  dummy boolean;
BEGIN
  dummy := do_something();
END;
```

Sorry, but this is the only way in PL/SQL. This language is very strict in definitions of procedure and function and you cannot make a function call without handling the result. But you can make a procedure as it is shown in example above.

It will define automatically where to choose the function and where the procedure.

**EDIT**

As far as there are people who do not trust me (sometimes I really tell bad things so doubts are allowed :) ) this is the test:

```
declare
  myresult boolean;

  function do_something return boolean
    is
  begin
    return true;
  end;

  procedure do_something
    is
      dummy boolean;
  begin
    dummy := do_something();
  end;
begin
  myresult := do_something();

  do_something();
end;
```

works well.

Comment: @Simn, Wouldn't it give a `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` ?

Comment: No... that's because you defined it within a an anonymous block. Try to do the same in schema level

Comment: I think the schema-level example does not work because you cannot create even a package with a name of existing table. So it is done a bit differently inside of the code to support polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful alternative to assigning a dummy variable:

```
DECLARE
  FUNCTION f_yes RETURN boolean IS
  BEGIN
    return true;
  END f_yes;
BEGIN
  IF f_yes THEN
    null;
  END IF;
END;
```

This is slightly more helpful when there are functions of different return types you want to call without using their results. It's also helpful for writing empty `IF` statements, which could be useful to to simplify code by eliminating possibilities for the real condition you want to match in a later `ELSIF`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation and the shortest solution I've come up is wrapping it in an IF statement:

```
if do_something then
  null;
end if;
```